# QGIS symbol size on final jpg of map different to size in print composer canvas

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer

I've set map symbol sizes for a layer in pixels (16) in the main map canvas window, and this has transferred to the map composer canvas A4 portrait size, and the size of the symbols looks OK.  However when I save/export the map composer as a JPG, the main map looks OK, but the symbols appear a lot smaller, too small in fact?[![this is the screeshot of the print composer window][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJcBS.jpg, and here is a screenshot of the finsished map at A4 size:[![[1]][1]

Comment: what did you set the DPI to when you "printed" the map?

Comment: Hi, I saved it as a 300 dpi JPG.  I can send you screenshots on request (via PM)?

Comment: You need to resize your symbols by 300/72 or 300/96 I think

Comment: Hi, what does this mean in terms of points/pixels?  Another possible solution would be to reduce the DPI, or reduce the number of layers in the project, to increase available RAM?

Comment: You could define symbol sizes in mm rather then pixels. I've never tested this, but I'd expect that to produce a predictable result on 'paper' (including an image or pdf) whereas I'd use symbol sizes in pixels for a predictable result on the QGIS map canvas itself. You can also define symbol sizes in map units if you want a predictable result in terms of the amount of the map a symbol covers.